# Android ListView exception on custom item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm using a simpleCursorAdapter to load a ListView.

The ListView items are defined by XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns: android......
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listDate"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:marginBottom="3dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:marginBottom="3dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I pass that listItem id to the ListView's adapter I get a FATAL EXCEPTION on resource type 0x12.

If I pass android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, it doesn't throw a FATAL EXCEPTION, but it also doesn't do what I need to do.

All of the documentation indicates that I can use a custom layout for the items retrieved by the adapter. That is exactly what I need to do.

How do I pass a ***custom*** layout to a ListView adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very good tutorial to understand making custom adapter

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: Let's assume that I don't want to reimplement SimpleCursorAdapter: What *exactly* does SimpleCursorAdapter expect as an item layout?

Comment: `BaseAdapter` will be the best for implementing your list view, try implementing it with it.

Comment: I implemented CursorAdapter with newView() and bindView() methods. That works. It is extremely odd that SimpleCursorAdaptor requires everything needed to do this in its constructor, and its documentation leads one to believe that this is possible. I'll write it off to "SimpleCursorAdaptor and SimpleJack: peas in a pod"